# localhost behaves like cross domain on same machine same port

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**In order to refrain from Cross-Domain between JavaScript on localhost, and Aspx on computername which is actually the same Machine, the following trick is applied** :

JavaScript opens http://localhost:port/site/page1.aspx on Machine A, which does response.redirect() on page_load() to http://computername/site/page2.

Upon completion, Page2 does response.redirect() back to http://localhost:port/site/page1.aspx?ReturnValue, and ReturnValue is copied within page1 to a client field, so the original calling JavaScript could access it.

**Problem is Access Denied error occurs although Javascript and page1 are supposed to be considered same domain. Only when page2 is opened with http://localhost/..., there is no problem.**

**Any idea why this happens ?**

Comment: sounds like you could use the `window.name` "transport"..

Comment: The cross domain protection will block the first request to a different domain. As of that page2 will never be called and the browser will never get a redirect back to localhost. You cant get around this, otherwise bad code could also use this technique.

Comment: page2 seems to be called when on same machine, and when on different machine. The redirect back to localhost works only when on same machine. Strange though why Access Denied from JavaScript to page1 when on same machine as localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the problem you need to understand how a redirect works. A redirect is a server response containing a instruction to redirect (a `Location` header). A redirect does not happen on the server but in the browser, it is just an instruction for the browser to go to a different page.

So the sequence will look like this:

1. JavaScript: requests `http://localhost:port/site/page1.aspx`
2. Server: Response with the instruction to Redirect to `http://computername/site/page2`
3. JavaScript/Browser: tries to request `http://computername/site/page2` because of the redirect information.
4. But this will be still a request with its origin at `localhost:port` and because  `computername` is a different domain this request will be blocked. As of that there will never be a request to `http://computername/site/page2`  and as of that no redirect to `http://localhost:port/site/page1.aspx?ReturnValue` is generated.

Comment: In this specific case, Page 1 is run from Visual Studio on its ASP.Net engine, and Page 2 is run on IIS on same Machine. The redirect works from Page 1 to Page 2 and also back from Page 2 to Page 1. What doesn't work is trying to retrieve the value in the original JavaScript code. Would appreciate if you could relate to why this retrieve doesn't work. Kind thx

Comment: @user2595302 It does not matter if the page is created using asp, php, node or if it is a redirect of s server rule, nor does it matter if it is on the same machine. The only important thing is the _domainname_ and _port_  combination.

Comment: OK. I understand "domainname + port" is the main thing. Therefore it works fine when everything is accessed as localhost:port. However, one thing still not clear : when flow is JavaScript -> http: //localhost:port/page1 -> http: //computername/page2->http: //localhost:port/page1 -> JavaScript, page 1 is opened as localhost:port both from JavaScript at beginning and from Page 2 at mid way, any yet the error is raised. Why is that so ?

Comment: Because of **4.** you script is loaded on a page on `localhost:port`, and requesting `localhost:port/site/page1.aspx`  this requested page redirects to `computername/site/page2`  but `computername`  is different to `localhost:port`  so the request **from** `localhost:port` **to** `computername` is block, and there will never be a response of `computername` with a redirect back to `localhost:port`

Comment: OK. Thank u very much.